# Removing characters from indices within multiple lists

Tags: python, list

Just a really quick question I cannot figure out for the life of me, although it seems simple...

How do I delete the last 2 characters of each 4th index of a list, in a list? So in less confusing terms:

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']

L = []

L.append(f)
L.append(p)
```

So now L is:

```
L = [['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']]
```

How would I go about getting writing a loop that would get rid of the \n at the end of every 4th index, within both lists (that could also be extended for more than just the 2 lists I have above in the list)?

I just want it to re-return L, without those \n's at the end of those last indices.

Comment: Is it fixed that of every list will have 4 elements ?

Comment: `L.append([x.strip() for x in f])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']

L = []

L.append(f)
L.append(p)

for i in range(len(L)):
    L[i][3] = L[i][3].rstrip('\n') # Use rstrip to strip the specified character(s) from the right side of the string.
print L

>>[['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap']]
```

Comment: These answers were fantastic, but this one worked the fastest, and most simply. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']

L = []

L.append(f)
L.append(p)
#iterate through every element in the list and 
#apply simple slicing 
for x in L:
    x[-1] = x[-1][:-1]
```

Output -

```
[['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove new lines and white space only from the 4th index with list comprehension:

```
>>> f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
>>> p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']
>>> [x[0:3]+[x[3].rstrip()] for x in [f]+[p]]
[['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap']]
```

Or `map` equivalent:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0:3]+[x[3].rstrip()],[f]+[p]))
[['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap']]
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments:

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']

L = []

L.append([item.strip() for item in f])
L.append([item.strip() for item in p])
```

Or in one step:

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']

L = []

for lst in [f, p]:
    L.append([item.strip() for item in lst])
```

Or shorter:

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']

L = [[item.strip() for item in l] for l in [f, p]]
```

Last but not least, literally answering your question; if you need to *specifically* strip certain indices from a list of lists:

```
L = [['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']]
for lst in L:
    lst[3] = lst[3].strip()
```

By default, `strip()` strips from whitespace characters, see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
f = ['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n']
p = ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']
L = []
L.append(f)
L.append(p)

for i in L:
    i[3] = i[3].rstrip('\n')

>>> [['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap']]
```

Comment: This will give a result like this. `[['yes', 'no', 'tot', ['yes', 'no', 'tot']], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp']]]`

Comment: Yeah, I just realized. I have got the example corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

For getting each 4th element from the list use this part: `i[3::4]`

For removing last two symbols from item: `x[:-1]`

The output script:

```
for i in L:
    i[3::4] = [ x[:-1] for x in i[3::4]]
```

Result:

> [['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop'], ['ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap']]

Comment: Elegant solution:)

Comment: `[3::4]` return each 4th element from the list. For the list `['yes', 'no', 'tot', 'foop\n', 'ick', 'throw', 'tamp', 'lap\n']` it will return `['foop\n', 'lap\n']`